# Sublime Text 3 breaks OctoGate firewall

Tags: firewall, sublime-text-3

Since I have no other place to ask I'll ask here.

My school is using an OctoGate firewall to block certain sites like reddit and youtube, these are blocked via their domain name and direct IP access is blocked as well. Because we can't install programs and I like Sublime Text more than Notepad++ I downloaded the portable version and I'm using that as my text editor, however once I open Sublime Text the firewall starts acting weird.

All of the sudden websites like Reddit work and sites that are normally not blocked by firewall result in a connection error. Nobody at my school knows a cause for this problem and I'm wondering how a portable application can have such a weird effect on an otherwise locked down system.

Maybe someone here knows an answer